# failed to build project using libpjsipjni.so

Tags: android-ndk

[image]I get this error when im trying to build my project

failed can not load library "libstlport_shared.so"neede by libpjsipjni.so; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:746):library"libstlport_shared.so"not found despite 
i hgot this line  while build 
have this line in my build ([armeabi-v7a] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libstlport_shared.so)

is  ndk-build cause this error

Answer (score 0):

In `jni/Application.mk` you likely have

```
APP_STL := stlport_shared
```

To fix your problem, put line

```
System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
```

somewhere before you load "libpjsipjni.so".
See an example in [CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/gingerbread/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html)

Alternatively, change  `jni/Application.mk` to use

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```